# how to group multiple 3d objects as one using AR core

Tags: java, android, arcore

here i am displaying multiple 3d object in scene (check below pic ) 
[image]

and here i am having 3 3d model objects and now is it possible to to group the the 3d model objects ex. if i move one 3d object then other 2 3d objects also needs to move .Is it possbile to achieve this with out using the unity & cloud anchors

below is my code

```
package com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.hellosceneform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;

import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;


public class HelloSceneformActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String TAG = HelloSceneformActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;

  private ArFragment arFragment;
  private ModelRenderable andyRenderable;

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
      return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ux);
    arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);

    // When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads its resources in the background while returning
    // a CompletableFuture. Call thenAccept(), handle(), or check isDone() before calling get().
    ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, R.raw.andy)
        .build()
        .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
        .exceptionally(
            throwable -> {
              Toast toast =
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
              toast.show();
              return null;
            });

    arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
        (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
          if (andyRenderable == null) {
            return;
          }

          // Create the Anchor.
          Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
          AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
          anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

          // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
          TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
          andy.setParent(anchorNode);
          andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
          andy.select();
        });
  }


  public static boolean checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(final Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.N) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or later");
      Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires Android N or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      activity.finish();
      return false;
    }
    String openGlVersionString =
        ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getDeviceConfigurationInfo()
            .getGlEsVersion();
    if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later");
      Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
      activity.finish();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group 3D objects together by using the `.setParent()` method. When an object is transformed (moved, rotated, or scaled), the child objects are also transformed.

The Solar System sample demonstrates this in [`createSolarSystem()`](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/SolarActivity.java#L357). The planets are made children of the sun, and the moon is made a child of the Earth node.

You can then position the object relative to the parent by using `setLocalPosition()`. Such as [positioning the planet in solarActivity](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/solarsystem/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/solarsystem/SolarActivity.java#L449):

```
Planet planet =
    new Planet(
        this, name, planetScale, orbitDegreesPerSecond, axisTilt, renderable, solarSettings);
planet.setParent(orbit);
planet.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(auFromParent * AU_TO_METERS, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the nodes yourself and simply move each node in the group when you move one, by applying the same transformation to each one.

In high level terms - create a group, or array or some sort of collection for your nodes, whatever works for your application.

Then when you want to move the group, you can loop through each node and for each one apply the same transformation - e.g. in the example below, all will have the translation (-0.05f,0,0) applied:

```js
        //Looping over each node in your group
        {
             //For each node, get the current Pose and transform it then set a new anchor at the new pose
             Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
             Anchor nextAnchor = [Get the next anchor node in your array or group]
             Pose oldPose = nextAnchor.getPose();
             Pose newPose = oldPose.compose(Pose.makeTranslation(-0.05f,0,0));
             movedAnchor = moveRenderable(currentSelectedAnchorNode, newPose);
             [Update your array or collection or group with this 'new' movedAnchor]
        }
```

To actually move the individual nodes, the code below can be used. This actually deletes the node in the current position and recreates the new node in the target position:

```js
private AnchorNode moveRenderable(AnchorNode anchorNodeToMove, Pose newPoseToMoveTo) {
        //Move a renderable to a new pose
        if (anchorNodeToMove != null) {
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().removeChild(anchorNodeToMove);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"moveRenderable - anchorNodeToMove was null");
            return null;
        }
        Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
        Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
        Anchor markAnchor = session.createAnchor(newPoseToMoveTo.extractTranslation());
        AnchorNode newAnchorNode = new AnchorNode(markAnchor);
        newAnchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
        newAnchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

        return newAnchorNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by getting current position of all TransformableNode node.

and than assign new vector value to all of your nodes like **node1.setLocalPosition(localPosition);**

```
    private void modleMovement(TransformableNode node, String moveMent) {
            Vector3 currentPosition1 = new Vector3();
            Vector3 currentPosition2 = new Vector3();
            Vector3 currentPosition3 = new Vector3();
            Vector3 move = new Vector3();

            currentPosition1 =Objects.requireNonNull( node1.getLocalPosition());
            currentPosition2 =Objects.requireNonNull( node2.getLocalPosition());
            currentPosition3 =Objects.requireNonNull( node3.getLocalPosition());

            if (moveMent.equals("down")) {
                move.set(currentPosition.x, (float) (currentPosition.y - 0.1), currentPosition.z);
                localPosition = move;
            }

            if (moveMent.equals("up")) {
                move.set(currentPosition.x, (float) (currentPosition.y + 0.1), currentPosition.z);
                localPosition = move;
            }

     node1.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
    }
```